# How do you sample influxdb data at a specified time interval?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I have 'chunks' of data getting stored every 30 seconds. The timestamps on each row of a chunk is the same. The measurements and one of the tags are different. 
Is there a way to query the data so that I get the data from the last 24 hours but with timestamps of every x mins instead of 30 seconds? I don't need that fine a resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` time interval:

```
GROUP BY time(xm)
```

but you will need to apply some aggregation function on the field, for example `MEAN(field)` to get average value.

Doc: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill